# How to call multiple Async.waterfall parallel in Node.js

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I have a situation where I have 4 Async.waterfall functions and now I need to run them all parallel. is this possible using Async.parallel or I need to use some other function?

Answer (score 0):

With the current version of async (1.4.2) it's not doable. Refer to this feature request - https://github.com/caolan/async/issues/887.